# EventRelation - Insert error. You can only add up to one what relation

Tags: apex, event

I'm trying to insert an EventRelation record related to a custom object (Shared activities is enabled).

```
Id idEvent = someEventId;
Id idProductVItem = someObjectId;
EventRelation evR = new EventRelation();
evR.EventId = idEvent;
evR.RelationId = idProductVItem;
evR.IsWhat = true;
evR.IsParent = true;
insert evR;
```

I receive this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can only add up to one what relation.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shared Activities feature allows you to associate multiple Contacts (up to 50) to an Activity through the `WhoId`, table-ized as `EventRelation` and `EventWhoRelation`. It does not allow you to establish multiple `What` relations, to standard and custom objects other than `Contact`.

Here's a snippet from the [`EventRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) documentation:

> - An event can be related to up to *50 contacts* or one lead. These people may or may not be invitees. The number of allowed invitees is not affected by the number of related contacts. If a contact or lead is also an invitee, there is one EventRelation record for that person with IsInvitee and IsParent are set to true.
> - An event can be related to *a* lead, contact, resource, account, or opportunity.
> - An event can be related to *a* custom object that has the HasActivities attribute set to true.

Emphasis is mine. Also worth noting that while there is an `EventWhoRelation` object, a filtered subset of `EventRelations` representing all of the Contacts or Leads (up to 1 Lead) associated to the Activity, there's no `EventWhatRelation` - because you only get one.

If the `WhatId` field on the `Event` is populated, this is equivalent to having a `What` `EventRelation`, and will cause this error upon attempting to insert another one.